# How can I implement variable to <i> tag class in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, font-awesome

I'm trying add an icon with using awesome font.
I used bootstrap button type and it's working fine.But when i would like to add a social icon using  tag it does not seem.How can i do that ?

```
   <div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-social btn-@p.AuthenticationType.ToLower()" id="btn-socialID" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account"><i class="fa fa-@p.AuthenticationType"></i>@p.AuthenticationType</button><br /><br />
                }
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: The code looks fine. What does `@p.AuthenticationType` return?

Comment: It returns Google and Facebook.I checked several times to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do a `ToLower` here:

```
<i class="fa fa-@p.AuthenticationType.ToLower()">
```

Font awesome icons are all lower case, so it should pick them up if you do a `ToLower`. Remember that [HTML class names are case-sensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

E.g.

```
<i class="fa fa-google"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

Comment: Yes you right.Thanks.I overlooked it because of unsleeping.

Comment: I'm about to fall into that state in few hours! :)